# Chrome extension onload behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a settings page for a chrome extension. In my options.js file I want to initalize the settings with some default values and I use `window.onload = initSettings();` for that. In my `initSettings()` function I am trying to access an input from the DOM via `document.getElementById("someId")`. But this call always returns `null`. I thought that the `window.onload` event is fired after all of the DOM elements are in place.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have this in the top of my options.js file - It's been so long since I last played with extensions, I can't be sure it's of any help. Worth a shot..

```
// fires when script is first loaded
// can't do onInit directly here, because the DOM hasn't been loaded for options.html yet
// we just set an event listener for document.DOMContentLoaded - In that handler we can call onInit
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onInit, false);
```