# Waiting for an element to load in the page Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that when I load a page it perform a click on a button, now I'm delaying the click 2-3 second waiting for the page to load.

```js
function aggiungi() {
  document.getElementsByName("button")[0].click();
}

setTimeout(aggiungi, 2000);
```

This isn't very good, because sometimes the page loads slower or faster. so there is a way to : "the moment the page is ready click the button" ? 
in my background 'm using  if `(changeInfo.status == 'complete') { ... }` but it doesn't work well.

Comment: Please review to see if this is a duplicate of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12770238/125981

Comment: that is not working for me :(

Comment: If the new page loads in the same tab, that code will never run, because it belongs to the old page and hence is destroyed when the new page is loaded over in the tab. Look for answers that show how to preserve the state between two instances of content scripts when clicking to navigate to another page.

Comment: in which sense ?

Comment: ok my background page is done by searching for an url if it matches it call a file , if another url match it calls another file :in one of those file i tried : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){

});     but nothing