# Why can't I call an elementById using my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to make Chrome extensions, and one of my tests was to use the YouTube "like" bar. I have been trying to take the width of the like bar, and pass it in an `alert` function.

However, about **95%** of the time, I get a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. The other 5% of the time, it seems to work. What am I doing wrong / not doing?

This is my code so far:

1. `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "32": "icons/icon32.png"
    }
  }
}
```

2. `script.js`:

```
const likebar = document.getElementById("like-bar").style.width;
alert(likebar);
```

Comment: Your script is assuming the DOM has loaded when it is run. Sometimes it's right, the other times, the HTML is still loading. Here's a way around it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770238/chrome-extension-onload-behaviour/12770327#12770327

Comment: thanks for you response @enhzflep , but this still doesn't work more than 5% of the time. i even tried what had been suggested in the other answer, with no change in the success rate. could it be due to some way that YouTube loads its elements?

Comment: Sure, I guess so. Perhaps the thing is fetched with ajax and added after page-load. Something else you might consider is a mutation observer. Wait for and be told about modifications to the DOM tree.  - such as the like bar being appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be calling `likebar` while the page is still loading, meaning `document.getElementById("like-bar")` returns a null value as the element does not exsist yet.

Have a method that waits for that element to load, like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const likebar = document.getElementById("like-bar").style.width;
    alert(likebar);

})
```

Edited to remove 2 non-working solutions. The above was tested by running it in google chrome console before a YouTube page loads.

Comment: this only works like 5% of the time. maybe there is some mismatch in the way YouTube loads pages? if I use `setTimeout(myFunction, 5000)`, it works fine, but that feels like a stopgap measure rather than a fix.